# Reconfigure azure managed prometheus for aks container

Tags: azure, prometheus, azure-aks, azure-monitoring

aks cluster is in Resource Group RG1.
I configured insights, azure-managed prometheus and azure-managed grafana in RG2.
I then wanted to move prometheus and grafana in RG1, same as aks cluster.

in between, I deleted all resources and RG2 altogether.
I created a new prometheus in RG1, not linked yet to any aks.

I want to edit prometheus configuration for aks to now point to new prometheus but i cant find any way to update aks monitoring to point to new prometheus in RG1 while it still points to old prometheus of RG2 even though old prometheus and RG2 itself are deleted.

I tried disabling monitoring for aks but it still points to old prometheus.

Comment: To update the AKS monitoring to point to the new Prometheus instance in RG1, you can follow these steps:
1.  Open the Azure portal and navigate to your AKS cluster in RG1.
2.  Select "Insights" from the cluster's menu.
3.  In the "Monitoring" section, select "Container Monitoring".
4.  In the "Data Sources" tab, select "Prometheus".
5.  In the "Prometheus" tab, update the "Prometheus server URL" to point to the new Prometheus instance in RG1.
6.  Click "Save" to save the changes.
After completing these steps, AKS monitoring should now be pointed to the new Prometheus instance in RG1.

Comment: @Arko, thanks for your reply but i dont get the option "Container Monitoring" under Insights >> Monitoring

Answer (score 0):

Disable Insights with:

```
az aks disable-addons -a monitoring -n <Cluster> -g <ClusterRG>
```

Disable Prometheus for AKS:

```
az aks update --disable-azure-monitor-metrics -n <cluster-name> -g <cluster-resource-group> 
az k8s-extension delete --name azuremonitor-metrics --cluster-name <cluster-name> --resource-group <cluster-resource-group> --cluster-type connectedClusters
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/kubernetes-monitoring-disable)